# Formatting data during an attempt to print the next digit which comes after the decimal in a float number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing question 3.3 in the Snakify python problems series...
I tried to print the next digit after the decimal in a given float input and, despite it seems correct, the debugger leaves the message `TypeError at line 6: string indices must be integers`....

Anyone have an idea why this might be invalid? I tried and tried and kept trying to format data types but this is no good...

This is my code:

```
num = float(input())
intNum = int(num)
intLen = len(str(intNum))
i = str(intLen + 1)
strNum = str(num)
ans = strNum[i]
print(ans)
```

Comment: You set `i` to `str(intLen + 1)`; therefore it is a string. You can't use strings to index strings, i.e. you can't use `i` as you do next: `strNum[i]`. Why are you using `str()` when you set `i`? What's wrong with just `i = intLen + 1`?

Comment: `i` is of type `str` and it needs to be an `int`. Why do you convert `intLen + 1` to a `str`?

Comment: Yes, you are right, guys. Thank you.